# Nested Objects With YUI and Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, yui

I am working on a Javascript object that contains some YUI objects.  The key thing is, my object needs to contain it's own set of YUI tabs so that I can display multiple instances of my object on the same page and have the tabs control their own object instance.

I set it up as follows:

```
var Scheduler = function(divid,startDate,mode){

  this.tabView = null;
  ...

  this.init = function(){
    this.tabView.appendTo(this.calendar_cell);

    this.tabView.addTab( new YAHOO.widget.Tab({
      label: 'Day',
      content:'<div id="'+ this.calendar_day_div +'"  style="width:100%; height:auto;"></div>'
    }));

    var tab0 = this.tabView.getTab(0);  
    tab0.addListener('click', this.showWeek);

  }

  this.showWeek(){
    alert(this);
  }

});
```

Here's the problem. I would expect the alert(this); in this.showWeek to alert the instance of scheduler.  Instead, it's giving me the tab li.  I tried alerting this.parent and am given 'undefined' as an answer.

How should I set this up to do what I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [addListenter](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.util.Element.html#method_addListener) method takes a scope argument.  So you can change your call to the following to solve your problem (since you are using YUI):

```
tab0.addListener('click', this.showWeek, undefined, this);
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

When you attach a function to an event of an object (in this case the object held by tab0) then its usually that object that becomes the `this` context of the function when it executes.

Adjust your code like this:-

```
var self = this;
this.showWeek(){
  alert(self);
}
```